# Getting UserInfo.getSessionId in Visualforce page without controller

Tags: visualforce, user, session

is it possible to retrieve sessionid of a user from a visualforce page without using any custom controller?

Answer (score 16):

Per the documentation: [Global variables - $Api](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_api.htm)

You can use this expression in your VF page markup.

`{!$Api.Session_ID}`

Comment: both are same thing or there is any difference ??

Comment: They are the same thing — there's a heap of global variables available in VF to help with scenarios like this one